# Url rewriting rule not working

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have the following URL rewrite rule that doesn't get activated when I hit the following URL:

http://www.oldurl.co.uk/2008/06/salaries

```
            <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^http://www.oldurl.co.uk/20$(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newurl.com/20{R:1}" /> 
            </rule>
```

Can any help please?

Answer (score 1):

`$` is special character denoting end-of-string. Escape this character:

```
<match url="^http://www.oldurl.co.uk/20\$(.*)" />
```

Comment: If this `$` is actually neccessary and not a typo.

Comment: I have tried this and the rule still doesn't work, any ideas? Thanks for the help by the way.